# How to know the importance of all the variables and levels in them using Random Uniform Forest in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I have a dataset containing 3 parameters (Region( factors - say US,UK,Aus,NZ),Domain or Industry( factors - say IT,Electrical,Mechanical) and Scope - good or bad). Using Random Uniform Forest package in R gives importance of Region and Domain on the Scope(variable to be predicted), but it does not end up showing importance of all the categories  i.e, it calculates the importance of Region US,UK,NZ,AUS and Domain IT,Electrical and Mechanical individually on the scope. While showing it shows only top 6 or a few parameters, not all.

Is there any way to get all the importance values being calculated.

Thanks in advance  0

Comment: You could manually create 1-vs-rest factors before passing the training data to the random forest.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Can you explain me please , coz all the importances are being calculated but I don't know from where to find and extract it...